# How do I add & remove values from a hidden input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="hidden" id="values" value="1,2,1,3" />

<a href="#" id="add" data-value="4">add</a>

<a href="#" id="remove" data-value="1">remove</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add').click(function()
    {
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');

        //add to $('#values')

        return false;
    });

    $('#remove').click(function()
    {
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');

        //remove all values that match in $('#values');

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**Examples**

a) Add, output would be: 1,2,1,3,4

b) Remove, output would be 2,3

Comment: Quit writing tags in titles, please.

Comment: And I just thought, why do you keep editing my questions. I never realized you just changed the titles. And sorry, it won't happen again ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with basic JavaScript functions and some jQuery goodies. Have a look at the documentation of the individual functions to learn more about them.

**Add:**

```
$('#values').val(function(i, v) {
    var arr = v.split(',');
    arr.push(value);
    return arr.join(',');
    // or actually easier in this case:
    // return v ? v + ',' + value : value;
});
```

**Remove:**

```
$('#values').val(function(i, v) {
    return $.grep(v.split(','), function(v) { 
        return v != value; 
    }).join(',');        
});
```

**Reference:** [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2), [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mTvEq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var values = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert($("#values").val());
    $("#values").val($("#values").val() + values);    
    alert($("#values").val());

    return false;
});
```

Remove would work the same way.

you can get the value from the hidden input with the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 var str = $('#values').val() + value;
 $('#values').val(str);
```

to add values to the textbox